# Match line numbering to original text (poemscol)

Tags: article, line-numbering, poemscol

I'm using the poemscol package to typeset a book of poems quoted by a character in a TV series.
Several of the catch lines from the series are from Shakespeare's plays.
What I'm wondering is how to set the line numbers to match the line numbers as in the original text.
Thank you.

EDIT: This is an example of a poem markup using poemscol and lineno (and fancyhdr). It uses the original text of the poem (not of the TV series). In this case it is a stanza from Scott's *Marmion* poem.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lineno}        % required by poemscol
\usepackage{poemscol}               % required to typeset poems
\usepackage{yfonts}                 % for blackletter font

\setverselinemodulo{5}              % place line numbers every 5 lines
\verselinenumbersouter              % place line numbers on outer (left on verso, right on recto pages
% \nolinenumbers                        % stop using poemscol line numbering

% declare gothic font
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textgoth}{\gothfamily}

% test of poemscol
\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Marmion, Canto XI. Stanza XXX.}
\attribution{Sir Walter Scott}
\begin{poem}
    \begin{stanza}
        \begin{linenumbers}
        % reset line numbering to accord with line number from original text
        \resetlinenumber[902]           % start line number at 902
        O, Woman! in our hours of ease,\verseline
        \index{O, Woman! in our hours of ease}
        Uncertain, coy, and hard to please,\verseline
        And variable as the shade\verseline
        By the light quivering aspen made;\verseline
        When pain and anguish wring the brow,\verseline
        A ministering angel thou!—\verseline
        Scarce were the piteous accents said,\verseline
        When, with the Baron's casque, the maid\verseline
        \verseindent To the nigh streamlet ran:\verseline
        Forgot were hatred, wrongs, and fears;\verseline
        The plaintive voice alone she hears,\verseline
        \verseindent Sees but the dying man.\verseline
        She stoop'd her by the runnel's side,\verseline
        \verseindent But in abhorrence backward drew;\verseline
        For, oozing from the mountain's side,\verseline
        Where raged the war, a dark-red tide\verseline
        \verseindent Was curdling in the streamlet blue.\verseline
        Where shall she turn!—behold her mark\verseline
        \verseindent A little fountain cell,\verseline
        Where water, clear as diamond-spark,\verseline
        \verseindent In a stone basin fell.\verseline
        Above, some half-worn letters say,\verseline
        {\bfseries\gothfamily Drink . weary . pilgrim . drink . and . pray .}\verseline
        {\bfseries\gothfamily for . the . kind . soul . of . Sybil .Grey .}\verseline
        \verseindent {\bfseries\gothfamily Who . built . this . cross . and . well .}\verseline
        She fill'd the helm, and back she hied,\verseline
        And with surprise and joy espied\verseline
        \verseindent A Monk supporting Marmion's head;\verseline
        pious man, whom duty brought\verseline
        To dubious verge of battle fought,\verseline
        \verseindent To shrieve the dying, bless the dead.
        \end{linenumbers}       % end custom line numbering
        \linenumbers*           % restart poemscol default numbering
        \end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\poemdate{1808}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable TeX code? Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch. I agree with your request. What does the OP mean by "original text"? Is it the script of the TV series or the original plays? As far as I am aware there is no standard numbering of the lines in Shakespear's plays.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll post an example.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include a sample poem markup.

In this example, poemscol line numbering **doesn't** get changed, but new line numbering (using lineno) _also_ appears. The poemscol line numbering starts at 1, the lineno numbering begins correctly at 902.